# Jetpack Compose add onClick will Recomposing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

my code

```
@Composable
fun AlbumPage(navHostController: NavHostController) {
   ElevatedButton(onClick = {
      navHostController.popBackStack()
   }) {
      Text(text = "click")
   }

   SideEffect {
        Log.d("tag","1111")
   }
}
```

when i set navHostController.popBackStack() in onClick{},log show twice

`14:53:34.452  D 1111`

`14:53:34.816  D 1111`

I remove navHostController.popBackStack()

```
@Composable
fun AlbumPage(navHostController: NavHostController) {
   ElevatedButton(onClick = {
      //navHostController.popBackStack()
   }) {
      Text(text = "click")
   }

   SideEffect {
        Log.d("tag","1111")
   }
}
```

log once

why?

Comment: Recomposition is not entirely a bad thing, it actually tells the UI that it needs to be updated. In this case it's telling the UI to dismiss the current screen and show the previous screen, so that's why it recomposes twice. If so many recomposition occurs while scrolling, then it's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description of the source file `NavHostController.kt`

```
When the given navController
 * changes the back stack due to a [NavController.navigate] or [NavController.popBackStack] this
 * will trigger a recompose and return the top entry on the back stack.
 *
 * @return a mutable state of the current back stack entry
```

Comment: thanks,but I can't find this in NavHostController.kt